# Postman - Calling a function with callback defined in Collection pre-request scripts

Tags: postman

I'm trying to define a function that sends a request in a collection Pre-Request scripts:

```
 const doRequest = (callback) => {
    const echoPostRequest = {
        url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'headername1:value1',
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify({ key: 'this is json' })
        }
    };
    console.log('ready to send request');
    pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
        console.log('request sent', err ? err : res.json());
        callback();
    });
}

glbl = {
    doRequest: doRequest
}
```

[image]

Then, in my main test (a simple GET to google), I have this in Pre-Request script:

```
glbl.doRequest(() => console.log('works!'));
```

However, the callback is never called, and the "request sent" log is never printed.
This is the output of my postman console:

```
ready to send request 11:58:02.257
GET http://www.google.com 11:58:02.262
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
I can provide the exported collection as well if it helps.

Thanks!

Edit: it I move everything in the Pre-request scripts of the request (not the collection), everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things happening here.

**Local scoping issues**

Your `glbl` variable is missing a `var`, `const` or `let` keyword.

Missing this keyword does not cause the variable to bubble up and become global on it's own. The environment Pre-request Script and request Pre-request Script are of different scopes.

As you've experienced, when you move the script to solely the request level, everything is sitting in the same scope so this works fine.

**Creating global functions**

Postman has the facility to create your own global variables. This can be done programmatically through `pm.globals.set` and `pm.globals.get`.
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#accessing-variables-through-scripts

There are some limitations to these variables: you can only store strings in them, so the object and function that you've created will not persist if we don't do something to change their type.

In this case before we set any variables we need to ensure we:

- `toString` any functions
- `JSON.stringify` any objects

Now the Pre-request script for our collection will look like:

```js
const doRequest = (callback) => {
    const echoPostRequest = {
        url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'headername1:value1',
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify({ key: 'this is json' })
        }
    };
    console.log('ready to send request');
    pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
        console.log('request sent', err ? err : res.json());
        callback();
    });
};

const glbl = {
    doRequest: doRequest.toString()
};

pm.globals.set('glbl', JSON.stringify(glbl));
```

In order to use this at a request level, we need to update our Pre-request Script there too:

```js
const glbl = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('glbl'));
const doRequest = eval(glbl.doRequest);

doRequest(() => console.log('works!'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow. But then I don't understand why I am still able to acces glbl? And the doRequest attribute is accessible and executes fine up until the postman call. Would you mind explaining to me what happens here?

Comment: If you were to log out `glbl` or `glbl.doRequest` from within your request based Pre-request Script you'll see that nothing is there - so actually you aren't able to access it.

Comment: Adding a log just before the `doRequest` call, I have something: `glbl Object` (and see I don't have an error when calling `glbl.doRequest`, it means that there is something, right?)

Answer (score 0):

After several tests I found a very ugly hack to export JS objects from a pre-request script to an other.
Of curse you have to ensure that the script that expose values is [called before](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/#execution-order-of-scripts) the module that uses the exported stuff.

The hack came from the following considerations:

1. You can't export js values other than string in postman, but you can add properties in the modules exposed by nodejs, so I imported the "util" module of nodejs and injected stuff there.

```
const util = require("util");
util.myExport = {
  myMethod(){
    // ...
  }
};
```

2. The `pm` object exposed is different in each script executed by postman (`require("util").myExport.pm === pm` returns `false` if `require("util").myExport.pm` was defined in another module), and only the current one can perform operation, so if I want to use pm in some of the exported method, I have to pass a reference of the current `pm` object. otherwise no method can be invoked.

```
const util = require("util");
util.myExport = {
  myMethod(_pm){             // note that `_pm` is the reference passed here,
    _pm.sendRequest(/*...*/) // otherwise this line wont work
  }
};
```

3. If you define an asynchronous function (such as a wrapper for setTimeout), it wont open the new process (nor thread, as well as with Promise or async/await functions) unless you use the properties exposed in the caller module. So you can not perform asynchronous operation if you are not using the current module stuff.

```
const util = require("util");
util.myExport = {
  myMethod(scope){
    scope.setTimeout(() => { // async function from the caller module
        scope.pm.sendRequest(/*...*/) // pm from the caller module
      }, 9999)
  }
};
```

4. Now you are ready to go! Just import the nodejs "util" module to have your functions in the current module, then you can call them as usual.

```
const util = require("util");
util.myExport.myMethod(this)
```